Page width change with trading widget in code block
I'm building a site for a coin and want to include a trading widget from Jupiter.
I've copied the code provided by Jupiter -below- and although the widget itself works well, it changes the width of my page.
I've tried various options but haven't managed to fix it.
Here's the code in the page header:
<script src='https://terminal.jup.ag/main-v3.js'></script>

And the code snippet for the widget inserted as a code block on the page:
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="integrated-terminal"></div>
  <script>
    window.Jupiter.init({
      displayMode: "integrated",
      integratedTargetId: "integrated-terminal",
      endpoint: "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
      formProps: {
        fixedOutputMint: true,
        swapMode: "ExactIn",
        initialOutputMint: "DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263",
      },
    });
  </script>
</div>

I tried changing the div style, removing it altogether, changing the section width.

I've tested your code on JS Fiddle and it seems to run fine. Even a local run of the code is working as intended.
One thing you can try is to set a max-width: x; property:
<script src='https://terminal.jup.ag/main-v3.js'></script>
<div style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="integrated-terminal"></div>
  <script>
    window.Jupiter.init({
      displayMode: "integrated",
      integratedTargetId: "integrated-terminal",
      endpoint: "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
      formProps: {
        fixedOutputMint: true,
        swapMode: "ExactIn",
        initialOutputMint: "DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263",
      },
    });
  </script>
</div>

